# Vk бот на Python не видит сообщения в беседах

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

Вечер добрый. Сегодня дорабатывая своего бота, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что он не замечает сообщения в сторонних беседах, где сообщество не является создателем ( без синей галки ). Начал изучать данный вопрос более подробно, наткнулся на библиотеку `vk_api.bot_longpool`, переписал код под неё, и если при библиотеке `vk_api.longpool` бот не отвечал на сообщения чисто в беседах, то при `vk_api.bot_longpool` он перестал отвечать везде, даже в личных сообщениях. Ниже приложу код с библиотекой `vk_api.longpool` и с `vk_api.bot_longpool`

Код с библиотекой `vk_api.longpool`:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import vk_api
import time
import random2
import json
from config import config_pass
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from enum import Enum

token = config_pass

bh = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
give = bh.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(bh)

def send(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

def sendchat(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'peer_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
       if event.to_me:

          message = event.text.lower()
          id = event.user_id
          chat_id = event.peer_id

          if message == 'начать':
             send(id, '123')
          if message == '!бот':
             sendchat(chat_id, '123')
```

Код с библиотекой `vk_api.bot_longpool`:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import vk_api
import time
import random2
import json
from config import config_pass
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from enum import Enum

token = config_pass

bh = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
give = bh.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bh, group_id='айди моей группы')

def send(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

def sendchat(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'peer_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
       if event.to_me:

          message = event.text.lower()
          id = event.user_id
          chat_id = event.peer_id

          if message == 'начать':
             send(id, '123')
          if message == '!бот':
             sendchat(chat_id, '123')
```

При использовании первого варианта кода - бот не отвечает только в беседах, при использовании второго варианта - бот не отвечает нигде. Надеюсь на любой фидбек :D

Answer (score 0):

хоть и поздновато, но скажу:

```
event.text
```

меняется на

```
event.obj['message']['text']
```

то же самое с пир_ид, там будет `event.obj['message']['peer_id']`